# How can I see which keys have been missed?

Tags: redis

I'm seeing a lot of cache misses on our Redis instance and I'm assuming this is due to a programming error where keys are looked up which were never stored.

I can run `MONITOR` to see all commands live, but that is impossible to follow and also doesn't seem to indicate if a key was hit or missed.

Does Redis itself provide any means to see which keys have been missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Redis `info` command contains `keyspace_hits` and `keyspace_misses` in   its various statistics. `keyspace_misses` will increment every time you ask to read from a key Redis doesn't have.

If you need more granular information I suggest modifying your cache fetch logic to write missing keys to a Redis sorted set or list so you can see which keys are going missing. You'll have to also come up with a way of purging this data periodically so it doesn't grow out of control, unless your total keyspace is pretty limited.

Answer (score 2):

It's become possible starting with Redis 6.0. New key 'm' added:

> m     Key miss events (events generated when a key that doesn't exist is accessed)

For example, you can see missed keys in console with 'redis-cli':

```
user@redis-server:~# redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events Km
OK
user@redis-server:~# redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__key*__:*'
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
"psubscribe","__key*__:*",1
"pmessage","__key*__:*","__keyevent@0__:keymiss","<< actual data >>"
......
```

source: https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Comment: [This article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elasticache-redis-keyspace-notifications) is useful if you're using AWS.